# Can not find NVIDIA driver after stop and start a deep learning VM

Tags: google-cloud-platform, debian, nvidia, nvidia-smi

**[TL;DR]** First, wait for a couple of minutes and check if the Nvidia driver starts to work properly. If not, stop and start the VM instance again.

I created a **Deep Learning VM** (Google Click to Deploy) with an A100 GPU. After stopping and starting the instance, when I run `nvidia-smi`, I got the following error message:

> NVIDIA-SMI has failed because it couldn't communicate with the NVIDIA driver. Make sure that the latest NVIDIA driver is installed and running.

But if I type `which nvidia-smi`, I got

> /usr/bin/nvidia-smi

It seems the driver is there but can not be used. *Can someone suggest how to enable NVIDIA driver after stopping and starting a deep learning VM*? The first time I created and opened the instance, the driver is automatically installed.

The system information is (using `uname -m && cat /etc/*release`):

> x86_64
> PRETTY_NAME="Debian GNU/Linux 10 (buster)"
> NAME="Debian GNU/Linux"
> VERSION_ID="10"
> VERSION="10 (buster)"
> VERSION_CODENAME=buster
> ID=debian
> HOME_URL="https://www.debian.org/"
> SUPPORT_URL="https://www.debian.org/support"
> BUG_REPORT_URL="https://bugs.debian.org/"

I tried the [installation scripts](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/gpus/install-drivers-gpu#installation_scripts) from GCP. First run

```sh
curl https://raw.githubusercontent.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/compute-gpu-installation/main/linux/install_gpu_driver.py --output install_gpu_driver.py
```

And then run

```sh
sudo python3 install_gpu_driver.py
```

which gives the following message:

> Executing: which nvidia-smi
> /usr/bin/nvidia-smi
> Already installed.

Comment: After posting the question, the driver starts to work properly. I think it takes a couple of minutes to load the Nvidia driver in Deep Learning VMs.

Comment: Please answer your own question instead of commenting.

Comment: As you have already resolved the issue, can you post the procedure you've followed as Solution and accept it for the greater visibility to the community.

Answer (score 5):

After posting the question, the Nvidia driver starts to work properly after waiting for a couple of minutes.

In the following days, I tried stopping/starting the VM instance multiple times. Sometimes `nvidia-smi` directly works, sometimes does not after >20 min waiting. My current best answer to this question is first waiting for several minutes. If `nvidia-smi` still does not work, stop and start the instance again.

Comment: Interesting, thank you! I see the same issue from time to time. But waiting even 30-40 minutes doesn't help in my case, I have to reinstall nvidia drivers. Weird, because it installs the same version of nvidia...

Answer (score 4):

also ran into this issue. if it helps someone, running following command [[1](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=843914)] fixed it for us:

```
$ sudo apt-get install linux-headers-`uname -r`
```

this was on debian 11.

[log](https://gist.github.com/siddhsql/2a263d61016fb3e5187952fe5cbe509a)

Comment: instant fix for me too. Unlike on the source I didn't need to install drivers afterward.

Answer (score 1):

What worked for me (not sure if it will go well to next starts) was to remove all drivers: `sudo apt remove --purge '*nvidia*'`, and then force the installation with `sudo python3 install_gpu_driver.py`.

In the `install_gpu_driver.py`, change line 230 to `return False` inside of the `check_driver_installed` function. Then, run the script.

Who uses docker may face this error `docker: Error response from daemon: could not select device driver "" with capabilities: [[gpu]]` and have to reinstall the docker too.  This [thread](https://github.com/NVIDIA/nvidia-docker/issues/1243) helped me.

Comment: But then if you reboot again, the driver can fail, right? It is not really a fix to the problem in question.